# How to recursivly download RPM dependencies?

Tags: linux, bash, redhat, rpm, yum

I want to write a mini script that downloads all the recursive dependencies of an RPM package in Linux RedHat.

When I use:

```
repoquery -a --requires --recursive --resolve PACKAGE_NAME
```

I'm not getting all the recursive dependencies, but when I use:

```
repoquery -a --tree-requires PACKAGE_NAME
```

I'm getting all the dependencies but I'm not getting a usable list that I can pipeline into `yumdownloader`.

What should I do?

Comment: Postprocess the list.

Comment: how? I'm new to bash scripting

Comment: Have you seen `yum`'s `downloadonly` plugin?

Comment: yes, I tried it too, and it doesn't retrieve all the dependencies recursively

Comment: you're probably looking for http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50642/download-all-dependencies-with-yumdownloader-even-if-already-installed

Comment: Try yumdownloader --resolve

Answer (score 1):

You can try [repotrack](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/repotrack.1.html)
It will download one or more packages and all dependencies.

Comment: repotrack worked for me. It downloaded **all dependencies** needed for the RPM package. syntax:  `repotrack package_name`

Answer (score -1):

If you're from the future like me (Fedora 23+), where yum is getting replaced with dnf, and repotracker is no longer working, you might find [this bash script](https://github.com/picrin/rpmDownloader) useful.